# ggplot2: can't change axis.title.y angle with position = 'right'

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a basic plot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

If I want the y axis label not to be rotated, i can do that like this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = 
          element_text(color='red', angle=0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

And if I want it on the right side, I can do that like this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_linedraw() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right')
```

[image]

**But why can't I do both?**

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_linedraw() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
  theme(axis.title.y = 
          element_text(color='red', angle=0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

For reference:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5  ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.1    
 [4] lazyeval_0.2.0   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.3     
 [7] gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.3.4     yaml_2.1.13     
[10] Rcpp_0.12.12.5   grid_3.3.3       digest_0.6.12   
[13] rlang_0.1.2      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: `theme` has left and right axis arguments: `axis.title.y.right = element_t...` should do it

Comment: Thank you! That works. If you post as an answer i will accept. Weird though, that `color` seems to inherit from `axis.title.y` to `axis.title.y.right`, but not `angle`. Any insight?

Comment: I guess because one is more likely to want different `angles` when you have both showing...

Comment: According to the `ggplot2` source code in `theme.R`, `axis.title.y.right` inherits from `axis.title.y` which inherits from `axis.title` which inherits from `text`.

Comment: Sorry, added as answer now. Maybe this worth raising on `ggplot2`'s github page (or mailing list), as it seems like reasonably unexpected behaviour that `tidyverse` tries to avoid.

Comment: @hrabel Not sure why you think this is "unexpected behaviour". It's a simple matter of inheritance. `axis.title.y` inherits from `axis.title`. Do you think that's "unexpected behaviour" as well?

Comment: Why does `axis.title.y.right` inherit `color` from `axis.title.y` but not `angle`? This might be beyond my knowledge of R and inheritance

Comment: The current version of ggplot2 has known theme inheritance bugs, see e.g. [here.](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2175) Some of these have been fixed in the development version. (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: @hrabel Ok I see what you mean. According to `theme-defaults.r`, `axis.title.y` has `angle = 90` as default, `axis.title.y.right` has `angle = -90` as default, so doesn't actually inherit `angle` from `axis.title.y`. `color` on the other hand seems to be passed down...

Comment: @ClausWilke ok, I will not add a new issue on github then. thanks

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to check whether the problem still exists in the current development version of ggplot2, and if it does then absolutely post an issue on github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ggplot2::theme` has left and right options for applicable components. So you can use `axis.title.y.right`.

Strange that you need to explicitly specify `right` when `axis.title.y` colours both `left` and `right` as you say in your comments, good spotting!

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_linedraw() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(color='red', angle=0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]